# Find all n complex roots of $x^n = k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to determine a formula for all n complex roots of the expression?

$x^n = k$

Where:

$x \in \mathbb{C}$

$k \in \mathbb{R}$

$n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n > 0$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Complex_roots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the complex roots of the unity :

If $ k\geq 0 $, then the solutions are $ x_{k}=\sqrt[n]{k}\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}\frac{2k\pi}{n}}$, $ k\in\left[\!\left[0,n-1\right]\!\right] $.

If $ k< 0 $ then the solutions are $ x_{k}=\sqrt[n]{-k}\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}\frac{\left(2k+1\right)\pi}{n}} $, $ k\in\left[\!\left[0,n-1\right]\!\right] $.